# Prevent page from going to the top when clicking a link

Tags: html

How can I prevent the page from "jumping up" each time I click a  link? E.g I have a link somewhere in the middle of the page and when I click it the page jumps up to the top.

Comment: please provide some of your JavaScript or HTML so we could help you more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's presume that this is your HTML for the link:

```
<a href="#something" id="some_id">Some link goes somewhere...</a>
```

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#some_id').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

> **Demo on: http://jsfiddle.net/V7thw/**

If you're not on jQuery drugs, try with this pure [DOM JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp):

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
        document.getElementById('some_id').onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: please click on the "gray check item" below the answer vote count, to accept it if it suits you best :)

Answer (score 6):

Is the anchor `href="#"`? You can set it to `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead.

If you are going to a prevent default please use this one instead:

`event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;`

Answer (score 1):

It will jump to the top if you set the link `href` property to `#` since it is looking for an anchor tag.  Just leave off the `href` property and it won't go anywhere but it also won't look like a link anymore (and make sure to handle the `click` even in javascript or else it really won't be of much use).

The other option is to handle the click in javascript and inside your event handler, cancel the default action and return false.

```
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
```

Comment: if he removes "href" link it will not be recognized as a "clickable" link item, see on my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4gmw/

Comment: Depends on what you're going for.  Added info on how to cancel the default action as well.

Comment: Yes I use the link just for the clickable property and I use javascript for the actual event. I will try it now thanks!